# Passing Data from ASP.NET Core to Typescript in Angular Cli-based App

Tags: c#, angular, server-side-rendering, asp-net-core-spa-services, spa-template

I am trying to setup a SPA where I can pass data from my appsettings.json to my clientside on server render. I followed the steps to configure SSR using the new SpaServices Templates

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular

However I am not understanding how to accomplish the task labeled here

> You can pass this to other parts of your app in any way supported by Angular

I see the example that is used is base_url, but it seems that base is injected into the page as a DOM element

```
 <base href='/'>
```

But it is not clear how to read other items in this manner. I am testing passing whether the app is Https or not, I have this section in my Startup.cs

```
options.SupplyData = (context, data) =>
{
    data["isHttpsRequest"] = context.Request.IsHttps;
};
```

and in main.server.ts

```
 { provide: 'isHttps', useValue: params.data.isHttpsRequest }
```

but it is in main.ts that I get lost, I have something like this

```
export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

export function getIsHttps() {
  // NO idea what needs to go here
  return "";
}

const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] },
  { provide: 'isHttps', useFactory: getIsHttps, deps: [] }
];
```

I am not sure how SpaServices injects the value on Prerender into the app (I looked through the code but it isn't clear to me). Is the value put on window? How do I read the value so I can inject into constructors on components?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer. You can use Angular's offical [TransferState](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState). You'll need to modify the following files

**app.server.module.ts** *(Add ServerTransferStateModule)*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

**app.module.ts** *(Add BrowserTransferStateModule)*

```js
import { BrowserModule, BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'universal-demo-v5' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This adds the modules needed to use TransferState.

You'll then need to provide the value sent by the dotnet Server on `main.server.ts` and add a dummy provider on `main.ts` so as to not raise a conflict.

**main.server.ts**

```js
import "zone.js/dist/zone-node";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from "@angular/platform-server";
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { provideModuleMap } from "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader";
import { createServerRenderer } from "aspnet-prerendering";
export { AppServerModule } from "./app/app.server.module";

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: "BASE_URL", useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl},

      //Added provider, ServerParams is the data sent on Startup.cs
      { provide: "SERVER_PARAMS", useValue: params.data.ServerParams }
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then(html => ({ html }));
});
```

**main.ts** *(Add dummy provider and bootstrap app only when DOM finished loading. This will give us the time to fully save object on TransferState)*

```js
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: "BASE_URL", useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] },
  { provide: "SERVER_PARAMS", useValue: "" }
];

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic(providers)
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Finally, we save the server provided object on `app.component.ts` on the TransferState

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from "@angular/platform-browser";

const SERVER_PARAMS = makeStateKey("serverParams");
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverParams: any;
  // Provider set on main.ts and main.server.ts
  constructor(@Inject("SERVER_PARAMS") private stateInj: string, private state: TransferState) {
    this.serverParams = this.state.get(SERVER_PARAMS, null as any);

    if (!this.serverParams) {
      this.state.set(SERVER_PARAMS, stateInj as any);
    }
  }
}
```

**THATS IT**

Now you can use Transfer state on any component to get the data as so

*home.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from "@angular/platform-browser";

const SERVER_PARAMS = makeStateKey("serverParams");

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent {
  serverParameter = "PLACEHOLDER";
  constructor(public state: TransferState) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serverParameter = this.state.get(SERVER_PARAMS, "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I dove into this and tried to make it work, but unfortunately it's not meant to work like you or I thought it should work. "You can pass this to other parts of your app in any way supported by Angular" means it needs to be accessible to client side code either by using the global namespace or some other means (which I can't think of). When the app is rendered through the main.server.ts, you can embed variables from the server, but that doesn't mean they are available to the client app automatically...kind of a half baked solution in my opinion, and you and I are not the only ones confused by this (see https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1444).

I recommend you look for other methods of including server side data, like a config service on your application bootstrap that gets the config on startup or embedding a JSON object in the Angular hosting page that is written by the server side code.

Comment: I am doing that in main.server.ts. the issue I am having is what to put in main.ts. There is no params available in main.ts. Unless I am missing something

Comment: Ah, I see. So once you provide the isHttps in the provider array, you should be able to use it through dependency injection in any component. Declare it in the constructor on your component and angular will inject it. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it,.

Comment: It's not available unless I put it in main.ts in some way. Are you saying it doesn't need to be there for DI to work?

Comment: I haven't used SSR so I don't know for sure. The articles makes it sound like that's all you need to do. Let me set a demo and try this.

Comment: Richard, did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: I did, I tried it and didn’t get it to work. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok nice to know I am not crazy. There has to be something trivial missing as the old templates had the ability to do this.

Comment: I'm on a similar scenario. I can see the server value while loading (server side render), but when client side takes control, main.ts provides the value, not being able to use the server value i send. Did you find any workarounds??